# How can I wait for multiple child processes using the OCaml Unix module?

Tags: multiprocessing, ocaml

I'm trying to parallelize work. I'm trying to have subprocesses each take a piece of the work, then wait for the work to complete from the parent process.

The following solution seems to work for small examples:

```
let par_iter (items: 'i list) ~(f: 'i -> unit): unit =
  let orig_pid = Unix.getpid () in
  let rec loop = function
    | [] -> ()
    | h :: t ->
      match Unix.fork () with
      | 0 -> f h
      | _ -> loop t
  in
  loop items;
  if Unix.getpid () = orig_pid then 
    List.iter items ~f:(fun _ -> ignore @@ Unix.wait ())
  else
    exit 0
```

Usage:

```
let () =
  par_iter [1; 2; 3; 4] ~f:do_something_with_an_int;
```

The [contract of `Unix.wait`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Unix.html#VALwait) when there are multiple subprocesses is not very clear to me. Here I'm relying on the behavior where `wait`ing `n` times will wait for all and only `n` subprocesses to finish.

Does this solution rely on undefined behavior? Is there an alternative way to correctly implement `par_iter` such that it spawns work on child processes and waits for the work to finish?

> tested on OCaml 4.14.0

Comment: _tested on OCaml 4.14.0_  OCaml 5.0 (in beta) has some stuff that might interest you.

Comment: For others finding this question, I think this is the kind of OCaml 5 solution @chris is referring to: https://github.com/ocaml-multicore/parallel-programming-in-multicore-ocaml#task-distribution-using-channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original parent process already had some subprocesses, this can fail. Thus, IMHO it's not usable as a general library. You should use [`Unix.waitpid`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Unix.html#VALwaitpid) to wait specifically for the processes you created.